# Is there anyway to make changes to string in the capture group in re.sub?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So I replace the the link with the text of the link

```
text = re.sub('<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>','\\1',text)
```

example:

```
>>>text="<a href="SOME URL">SOME URL</a>"
>>>text = re.sub('<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>','\\1',text)
>>>print text
SOME URL
```

I would like it to output some_url

but adding .lower().replace(' ','_') doesn't help

```
>>>text = re.sub('<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>','\\1'.lower().replace(' ','_'),text)
SOME URL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. `re.sub` accepts a callable for its `repl` argument. [The docs make it pretty clear](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) but here's an example:

```
import re

re.sub(r'<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>',
       lambda match: match.group(1).lower().replace(' ','_'),
       text)
```

Comment: close enough, but s is the match object so need to add .group(1)

re.sub('<a href=\".*?\">(.*?)</a>', lambda s: s.group(1).lower().replace(' ','_'), text)

please add it to your reply so I can mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: Oh so it is. That teaches me to link the docs and not *read* them! :)

Comment: @Kameegaming that said, Davidos's suggestion to use a parsing library is generally best practice for trying to deal with X/HTML. [This famous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3058609) documents one answerer's descent into madness trying to stop regex+HTML

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I am not actually dealing with HTML, only a parsed wikipedia dump with a bunch of these "URLs" in them so I am really just text matching rather than parsing html

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of task i would consider a more mature package eg.: beautiful soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
BeautifulSoup('<a href="SOME URL">SOME URL</a>').find("a").text
    u'SOME URL'
```

Comment: agreed with the recommendation to use bs4, but as OP points out: he probably doesn't want to lowercase and un-space-ify the whole string.

Comment: then he should be more specific.

Comment: @DavidosKrausos the title is "Make changes to [the] string in the capture group." That seems pretty specific to me! :P

Comment: This is the right answer when someone is dealing with pure HTML I guess, for my case this wasn't the best solution as I only deal with these url markups and nothing else.